# How to add application to the "open from" menu

Tags: android

I'm making a custom application and I need to enable it to use it as a file picker (like Drive, and Fotografias, Solid Explorer in the attached screenshot)

I want to open one of my app activities in order to use it as a custom signature pad

My plan is to allow the user to sign and that whould be returned to the file input of the caller application

[image]

Currently I have a deeplink that allows me to open the signature activity, the signature is saved in the filesystem of the phone, and after that the user has to use the file explorer to select the signature

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent-filter for this purpose:
Read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

```
<activity android:name="com.yourapp.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.your_file_extension" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I tried with your example, deleting the path pattern (<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.your_file_extension" />) and its not working... i tried creating a simple html page with just an input file, and my application is not appearing as a valid source....

Comment: So specify please what currently you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to use my application to select images